# stop user interaction on masterview cell once clicked already

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

For `UISplitViewController`, I have a `UITableView` in my master view.

when I click on one of the cells, I modify the `DetailViewController` as follows:

```
 [self.detailVCObj.navigationController pushViewController:settingsVCObj animated:YES];
```

But, If I again click on the same cell,instead of doing nothing, a new view is again pushed.
How should I solve this?

Comment: why don't you try cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO; if clicked once ?

Comment: this will lead to dirty flags, there should be some simple and good solution for this. UISplitViewController is being used for a long time now.

Comment: you dont need to use any flag buddy!! in the end of didSelectRowatIndexpath, after your code to push view controller, addcell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: you mean whenever a cell is clicked, I make other cell's user interaction to YES, and this cell's userInteraction = NO?

Comment: actually this "cell" points to that particular selected cell and not the whole list of cells.

Comment: @Dpk your solution will lead to all cells being untappable since you never reset the user interaction.

Comment: @NikitaP you need to tap one row just once right?

Comment: @Dpk yes, or better, even if the cell is tapped multiple times, it shouldn't clutter the detail view with multiple instances of a single view one top of the other.

Comment: @NikitaP let me check some code using splitviewcontroller and will get back to you soon

Comment: @NikitaP please check the following tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial

Comment: and refer the answer of this question too, u will get it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451657/check-to-see-if-uiviewcontroller-has-already-been-created

Comment: @MattG yup, i agree, need to see whether there is any alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if(![[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[settingsClass Class]])
{
   // Push viewController
   [self.detailVCObj.navigationController pushViewController:settingsVCObj animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Why the conversion to `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Just to get all viewControllers in the navigation stack.. Is there any problem with this conversion??

Comment: just seems unnecessary which means it's going to get confusing at some point. Not technically wrong beyond that though.